# Is there a way to make a temporary list for this or fix the save results function?

Tags: python

My problem is that I temporarily append "total" score to result and it causes my save_results to crash with the error beneath. I don't know if there's a better way to sort results by total score or if my save_results can just be fixed.

```
def save_results_to_file(file_name, results):
    my_file = open(file_name, "w")
    for result in results:
        my_file.write("{}\n".format(";".join(result)))
    my_file.close()
    print("\nResult is now saved in the file!")
```

The error I receive is this.

```
line 130, in save_results_to_file
    my_file.write("{}\n".format(";".join(result)))
TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, int found
```

How the results are in the file

```
Sara;37;32;47;
Johan;44;29;34;
```

I believe it is caused by this where I temporarily append total in results where I print results by sorting by total score.

```
elif user_choice == "4":
    for res in results:
        varv_1 = res[1]
        varv_2 = res[2]
        varv_3 = res[3]
        total = int(varv_1) + int(varv_2) + int(varv_3)
        res.append(total)
    results.sort(key=lambda x:x[4])
```

Comment: result includes integer items, that causes the error

Comment: is there a way to fix that? @IoaTzimas

Comment: Of course there are. 1: do not store integers in the list or 2: convert the integer to a string before storing it: `res.append(str(total))` 3: probably many others and you do not give enough context to choose between them.

Comment: I have added a solution @Sultan please check and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result list includes integer items, that causes the error. Use this instead (it changes all integers to strings)

```
def save_results_to_file(file_name, results):
    my_file = open(file_name, "w")
    for result in results:
        my_file.write("{}\n".format(";".join([str(i) for i in result])))
    my_file.close()
    print("\nResult is now saved in the file!")
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I was trying to achieve this earlier but didn't know how to implement it correctly. Thank you very much. @IoaTzimas

Comment: Great happy to help. Please accept the answer so that it will leave the 'unanswered' queue. Cheers